# Trying to manage a Service-based Database in C# WPF

Tags: c#, database, wpf

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here, but I am inexperienced in using a database in C#.

I've followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mgtfxtjKoaA and I've gotten things to basically work they way they show, but I want control of my database's table more directly and I was using this document to try and figure out how: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/insert-new-records-into-a-database?view=vs-2019

The main problem is that from what I can tell, my table adapter's update method isn't adding the new row. At least when I try pulling the data I get nothing.

Here are the methods that handle both getting the database data and adding a new row in my EmployeeDirectory class

```
public static void InitializeWithTable(Employee_Directory.EmployeeDirectoryDataSet EmployeeDirectoryDataSet, Employee_Directory.EmployeeDirectoryDataSetTableAdapters.EmployeesTableAdapter EmployeesTableAdapter) {
            employeesTableAdapter = EmployeesTableAdapter;
            employeeDirectoryDataSet = EmployeeDirectoryDataSet;
            
            
            foreach (System.Data.DataRow DataRow in employeeDirectoryDataSet.Employees.Rows) {
                var Id = Guid.Parse(DataRow["Id"].ToString());
                
                var NewEmployee = new Employee(Id, DataRow["Name"].ToString(), DataRow["JobTitle"].ToString());

                employees.Add(NewEmployee);
            }

        }

        public static void AddEmployee(string Name, string JobTitle) {

            var NewEmployee = new Employee(Name, JobTitle);
            employees.Add(NewEmployee);

            //Add to database
            EmployeeDirectoryDataSet.EmployeesRow newRow = employeeDirectoryDataSet.Employees.NewEmployeesRow();
            newRow.Id = NewEmployee.Id.ToString();
            newRow.Name = NewEmployee.Name;
            newRow.Job_Title = NewEmployee.JobTitle;

            employeeDirectoryDataSet.Employees.Rows.Add(newRow);

            employeesTableAdapter.Update(employeeDirectoryDataSet.Employees);
        }
```

And my WPF windows loaded method that setups up the EmployeeDirectory.

```
 private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

            Employee_Directory.EmployeeDirectoryDataSet EmployeeDirectoryDataSet = ((Employee_Directory.EmployeeDirectoryDataSet)(this.FindResource("employeeDirectoryDataSet")));
            // Load data into the table Employees. You can modify this code as needed.
            Employee_Directory.EmployeeDirectoryDataSetTableAdapters.EmployeesTableAdapter EmployeesTableAdapter = new Employee_Directory.EmployeeDirectoryDataSetTableAdapters.EmployeesTableAdapter();
            EmployeesTableAdapter.Fill(EmployeeDirectoryDataSet.Employees);
            System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource employeesViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("employeesViewSource")));
            employeesViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();

            
            // Have the EmployeeDirectory handle interfacing with the table.
            // Set up this way more for demonstrating knowledge of OOP over anything else
            EmployeeDirectory.InitializeWithTable(EmployeeDirectoryDataSet, EmployeesTableAdapter);
            EmployeeListView.ItemsSource = EmployeeDirectory.Employees;
        }
```

If there is any thing else needed to clarify things, let me know. Thanks in advance for the help.

Edit: Here is my current project packaged up if anyone wants a closer look. It is a VS 2019 project
[Employee Directory](https://filebin.net/xkiqngiiwhwk4m0z/Employee_Directory.rar?t=mobba8ur)

Comment: Does `EmployeeDirectory.Employees` Has data when assigning to `ItemsSource` did you debug? or just checking on UI

Comment: Yes I did. Before I started trying to get data from the database, I manually added Employees to the directory. They would show in the UI just fine that way.